# Newton's Divided Difference Formula without given data point

Tags: numerical-methods, lagrange-interpolation

This is the original question:

> Let f(x)= sin((pi*x)/6) and P(x) a quadratic polynomial such that f(x)
> = P(x) at x=0,1, and 2. Find P(x) using Newton's Divided Difference Formula

Since Newton's Divided Difference Formula required the data of x0, x1, x2, but it is missing in the question.
Should I first convert the trigonometry question (sin((pi*x)/6)) into a quadratic polynomial, then find the data point of x0, x1,x2 by the quadratic equation?

But I am confusing of how to convert it into quadratic equation.
I only can solve sin((pi*x)/6)=0, x= 12n or 6+12n . And I am confusing of the next step.

Thank you so much

Comment: Your task is to find the quadratic polynomial $$P(x)=f(x_0)+f[x_0,x_1](x-x_0)+f[x_0,x_1,x_2](x-x_0)(x-x_1).$$ Your data is $(x_k,f(x_k))$. There is no mention in the task about roots of $f$ or $P$.

Answer (score 1):

You have the data...
$$
y_0=f(x_0)= \sin 0 = 0, \quad, y_1 = f(x_1) = \sin \frac{\pi}{6} = \frac 12,\quad y_2=f(x_2)=\sin \frac{\pi}{3} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.
$$

With this information, you can compute $f[x_0], f[x_0,x_1]$ and $f[x_0,x_1,x_2]$ and assemble the interpolating polynomial.